# Array of structs in C, am I going through each index in my program? Can I make it Dynamic?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-arrays

My program works fine, but without the if(listsize == list) condition it will let me continue to add movies, and the display works fine as well and all movies will continue to be displayed. However, when ending the program I get a smash stack detected error. Can I make this array of struct dynamic so that I can keep adding an indefinite amount of movies? Also, I'm just now learning structs and this is my first program using them, in my array am I correctly indexing and storing data in movie1, movie2, and movie3? It works, but I feel like im doing a lot of things wrong here. Also, I tried to use fgets to get a line of text for the movie title and director, but it would ask for the data and then wouldn't pause for the data to be entered, and would skip to asking for the director name, and then when data was entered it would loop a lot of print statements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define list 3

typedef struct{
  char title[25];
  char director[25];
  int release;
  int runtime;
} movieInfo;

void entermovie(movieInfo movie[], int i){
  printf("Enter the title of the movie: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", movie[i].title);
  getchar();
  printf("Enter the director of the movie: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", movie[i].director);
  getchar();
  printf("Enter the release date of the movie: ");
  scanf("%d", &movie[i].release);
  printf("Enter the movie runtime: ");
  scanf("%d", &movie[i].runtime);
    
}
void displaydata(movieInfo movie[], int listsize){
  for(int i = 0; i < listsize;i++){
    printf("Movie %d data:\n"
      "Title:        %s\n"
      "Director:     %s\n"
      "Release date: %d\n"
      "Runtime:      %d\n", i + 1, movie[i].title, movie[i].director, movie[i].release, movie[i].runtime);
  }
}

void askChoice(){
  printf("Enter 1 to add movie data\nEnter 2 to view the movie data stored\nEnter 3 to exit the program\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int listsize = 0;
  char choice;
  movieInfo movie1, movie2, movie3;
  
  movieInfo movies [list] = {movie1, movie2, movie3};

  while(choice != '3'){
    askChoice();
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    switch(choice){
      case '1':
        if(listsize == list){
          printf("\nMaximum storage reached\n");
          break;
          }
        entermovie(movies, listsize);
        listsize++;
        break;
      case '2':
        if(listsize == 0){
          printf("\n\nNo Movie data is currently stored\n\n");
          break;
        }
        displaydata(movies, listsize);
        break;
      case '3':
        break;
      default:
        printf("Please enter a valid choice\n");
        break;
      }
      

  }
  printf("Exiting the program, goodbye");

  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `s` at the end of `%[^\n]s`? Please let me know what bad tutorial is teaching this, so we can ask them to fix it.

Comment: You need to initialize `choice`. Otherwise you're testing an uninitialized variable on the first iteration of `while (choice != '3')`

Comment: Or just change that to `while (1)`. You don't need the test there, since you break out of the loop in `case '3':`

Comment: You can use `malloc()` and `realloc()` to make the array size dynamic.

Comment: @Barmar the s at the end was in a lot of posts I saw, with a lot of people correcting it, I just forgot to remove it. OK, initialize to anything other than 3!

Comment: Or do what I said in my second comment, you don't need that condition.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the stack smashing error. You can try using valgrind, it may detect it.

Comment: On making the array dynamic, its an array of structs, so how would I go about creating movieInfo movie4, and so on? is movie1, movie2, movie3 even necessary? can I just make list dynamic and not initialize movieInfo movies [list];?

Comment: You don't need `movie1`, `movie2`, etc. You never use them.

Comment: `movieInfo *movies = malloc(list * sizeof *movies)`

Comment: @Barmar Ok, that's where I have been getting lost. So where Is the data being stored? index 0 of movies should be movie1, index 1 should be movie2, etc, right? would it be entermovie(&movies[listsize] , listsize); to access 0,1,2, etc?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for that malloc line, I need to watch some YouTube videos on it before I try to implement it, I need to learn it

Comment: It's being stored in the array. You're just copying the values of `movie1`, etc. to the array. Which is undefined, because you never initialized them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an empty list:

```
int listsize = 0;
movieInfo *movies = NULL;
```

Use only `realloc()` to grow your list:

```
case '1':
    movieInfo *tmp = realloc( movies, (listsize + 1) * sizeof(movieInfo) );
    if( tmp == NULL )
        printf( "Error: Cannot expand list\n" );
    else {
        movies = tmp;
        entermovie( movies, listsize ); // listsize no longer out-of-bounds
        listsize++;
    }
    break;
```

`realloc()` will return `NULL` if unsuccessful.

The rest of your code does not need to be changed because of C's equivalence between pointers and arrays.

Consider improving the flow of option '2'. One wants to write clear, concise code.

```
case '2':
    if( listsize )
        displaydata( movies, listsize );
    else
        printf( "No Movies currently stored\n" );
    break;
```

Maybe move that test and message into `displaydata()` to make the higher level function 'cleaner'.

And, when the list is no longer needed:

```
if( movies )
    free( movies );
```

Comment: @Fe203 That super helpful! Thank you! I'm trying to break it down right now.

```
movieInfo *movies = NULL
```
this creates a pointer of type movieInfo called movies, that currently points NULL, rather than a garbage random address right?

```
movieInfo *tmp = realloc( movies, (listsize + 1) * sizeof(movieInfo) );
```

creates a pointer *tmp of type movieInfo, but I'm lost on how an array is created or what is actually happening without the []. When using realloc() what is happening? is it deallocating memory from movies, and allocating it to *tmp, and then reassigning it?

Comment: You need to learn about allocating chunks of "heap memory". Too much knowledge to fit into a comment. Briefly, `realloc()` receives a ptr (if NULL, realloc works like `malloc()`). If there's available room beyond the block pointed to, realloc() simply expands the block. If something else is there (can't expand) realloc() finds a large-enough block elsewhere and will shift the bytes to the beginning of the new, large block. It may return a different address (or NULL if request can't be satisfied.) The name of an array is equivalent to a pointer to that array. Think "memory addresses". :-)